# upgraded my vmware esxi host from 5.5 to 7.0 but cannot see existing datastores

Tags: vmware, esxi

performed an upgrade of my vmware esxi host from 5.5 to 7.0
(went from path 5.5 to 6.5 to 7.0)

esxi host has 3 NAS connected
1 of the nas (LenovoEMC™ px12-400r) has 3 datastores
after the upgrade, the host cannot see this 3 datastores but NAS is connected.
if i created a new partition in the NAS, my host can detect this newly created partition
but we cannot see this existing 3 datastores

we have opened a ticket with vmware support but their response is also extremely slow
can anyone assist or point out how do i resolve this?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Did this get solved?
Was it nessecary to go over 6.5?

Answer (score -1):

Does you check VMFS Compatibility? I suppose that VMFS version is lower than require for ESXI 7 this why you can't see your datastores.

To solve the problem you have to update VMFS File System. The only way is attach datastore to an old vsphere, create new LUNS and format with VMFS 6 then move all files to new datastore with vMotion.

Comment: vmfs5 is supposed to be compatible with versions esxi 6.5 and newer.